# jq: limitting all arrays in a complex json

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Trying the following code:

```
echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '..|= if type == "array" then [limit(3;.[])] else . end'
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  null,
  null
]
```

Expect it to produce short array:

```
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

JSONs I work with are big and complex. My goal is to shrink all arrays down to length 3. What I get is arrays of original length with lots of nulls.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If while the overall structure may be complex, the amount and arrangement of the arrays are not (e.g. no array is itself an item of another array at a position higher than 3, etc), you can simply address "all arrays" and shorten them independently from each other:

```
(.. | arrays) |= .[:3]
```

If, however, you need to cover those special cases, `walk` would be more appropriate as it descends the document tree in order and therefore will not leave over dangling parts after the trucation:

```
walk(if type == "array" then .[:3] else . end)
```

Comment: Ty. It helped me to write required script, but I still don't understand difference. No idea why I get NULLs in one case and don't get in the other.

Comment: @ruz Because with `.. |=` you iterate over the whole array and all its elements. In the case of the whole array it works fine, but when it tries to update elements `.[3]` and `.[4]` from the (previously truncated) array, their initial value is `null` (because they were truncated), and as not being an array they will be kept (i.e. reinserted) as is (`else .`). To chage your code to work properly, just update the arrays (`(.. | arrays) |= …`, [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UBE57QIVtR)) and it will be identical with my first solution (including its mentioned caveat).